# xml choice : single element should repeat

Tags: xsd

I want a document to consist only apples or oranges. I am creating an XML schema as follows:

```
<element name="fruit" type="myns:fruitType"></element>

<complexType name="fruitType">
    <choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <sequence>
        <element name="apple" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
          <element name="orange" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0"></element>
      </sequence>
      <sequence >
        <element name="orange" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
          <element name="apple" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0"></element>
      </sequence>
    </choice>
</complexType>
```

but this accepts the following as a valid element.

```
<fruit>
  <apple> apple1 </apple>
  <orange> orange1 </orange>
  <orange> orange2 </orange>
  <apple> apple2 </apple>
</fruit>
```

I want only the following to be valid:

```
 <fruit>
  <apple> apple1 </apple>
  <apple> apple2 </apple>
  .
  .
  <apple> appleN </apple>
 </fruit>
```

OR

```
<fruit>
  <orange> orange1 </orange>
  <orange> orange2 </orange>
  .
  .
  <orange> orangeN </orange>
</fruit>
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct schema should have been:

```
<complexType name="fruitType">
    <choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <sequence>
        <element name="apple" type="string" **minOccurs="1"** maxOccurs="unbounded">   
        </element>
      </sequence>
      <sequence >
        <element name="orange" type="string" **minOccurs="1"** maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </element>
      </sequence>
    </choice>
</complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<complexType name="fruitType">
    <choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <sequence>
        <element name="apple" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
                 </sequence>
      <sequence >
        <element name="orange" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
                  </sequence>
    </choice>
</complexType>
```

Comment: yes, because the schema suggested by you validated the documents which had no apples and oranges. The minOccurs constraint should have been 1.